# How to put an audio before a stream connection in Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, playback, internet-radio

I am new to programming and I am making a basic app for radio in which an introduction audio sounds when you press a button, then a second audio should appear until the network connection of the online radio is established.

I have managed to make the intro audio sound complete when I click, then silence is generated until the online radio plays, but I don't know how to put a second audio that detects the charging status before the radio plays. This is my code:

```
    fun MediaPlayerRadio(){
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(
            this@MainActivity,
            Uri.parse("https://radiolink.com")
        )
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }

........................................................................

    fun MediaPlayerIntroSound(){
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.SoundIntro)
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }

........................................................................


    fun click_Button_Radio(){
        btn.setOnClickListener(){
            if (btn.isSelected){
                btn.isSelected = false
                mediaPlayer?.stop()
            }else{
                btn.isSelected = !btn.isSelected
                MediaPlayerIntroSound()
                    mediaPlayer!!.setOnCompletionListener(object : MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
                        override fun onCompletion(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
                            MediaPlayerRadio()
                            }
                        })
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope you can support me with this.

Answer (score -1):

For this, you will have to use 2 media players, one for intro sound and another for actual sound.

While the time actual sound media player gets ready, you can play different audios on the intro sound media player.

To stop the intro audio player once the other player is ready, you can make use of a view model.

```
    //Play Media player

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity, R.raw.first_audio)
    mediaPlayer.start()

    // Add completion listener, so that we can change the audio 
    // once the first one is finished

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
        mediaPlayer.release()
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this@MainActivity, R.raw.second_audio)
        mediaPlayer.start()
    }

    // We are observing a MutableLiveData of Boolean type, 
    // once it is true we will stop the intro media player 
    // and start the radio player

    viewModel.isPlayerReady.observe(this) { isReady ->
        if(isReady) {
            mediaPlayer.stop()

            // Start radio media player
        }
    }

    // This is how I am changing the value of MutableLiveData

    demoBtn.setOnClickListener {
        viewModel.isPlayerReady.value = true
    }
```

I have tested the above approach and it works fine as expected.

---

Steps to link a view model to the activity:

1. Add the dependency:  `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"`
2. Make a view model class and a mutable live variable of type boolean in it.

   `class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {` 
   `val isPlayerReady = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()`
   `}`
3. Link view model with the activity.

`class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {`

```
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

    ....
}
```

Comment: Hello friend, I have tried to do what you indicate, and everything is great except the viewModel part, it tells me that it has an Unresolved reference, do you know how to solve that part?

Comment: Have you add the dependency of view model ?

Comment: @YulianLoyola check the new update with the view model integration